# How to get JSON out of gzip-ed .json file in S3 from frontend Javascript?

Tags: amazon-s3, axios, gzip

Here's a simplified version of the issue I'm running into - basically I'm just trying to get data out of S3 which is in a .gz file (MOCK_DATA.json.gz)

I'm using axios to try and retrieve the data from the S3 URL. I've heard that generally, there's a way to get the response automatically decompressed + decoded by just setting your headers to allow content-encoding: gzip.

At a high level, I have something like this:

```
axios.getRequest("http://<my bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/MOCK_DATA.json.gz", {headers: headers})
     .then(response => // do stuff with response)
```

When I try to log the response, it looks like its stilled gzipped and I'm not sure the best way to approach this.

I've tried setting some headers on the request to specify the expected content type but so far to no avail.

I could also try just manually decoding the response once it has been received but I've been told that it should be happening automatically. Does anyone have tips on how I should be approaching this or if there might be a misunderstanding on how decoding on the client side works?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue - rather than messing around on the frontend code / the consumer of the .gz file, I just had to add some metadata to the S3 object itself.

It had automatically set the content type on upload:

`Content-Type: application/x-gzip`

But I had to also set:

`Content-Encoding: gzip`

In the S3 Object properties in order to get the value decoding properly when dealing with it from the JS code.